# How upload data and files using ajax and express?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a  for a signup where the user give me a: login, password and an image(profile pic). This is my form:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1>Sign-Up</h1></legend>
    <form>
        <label htmlFor="login">Login</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Login" id="signup_name">
        <br>
        <label htmlFor="passwd">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="signup_passwd">
        <br>
        <label for="imageFile">Image</label>
        <br>
        <input name="image" type="file" id="imageFile"/><br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="signup()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

The script takes the information and send it to the database, except for the image. As for the image, I want the server to store it on diskStorage, locally on a folder. I have a folder named "FCImages" where I want to store those images, this folder is located at /home/$user/project/server/FCImages (Linux).
So my question is, how do I get this image from the , send it to the server, then the server store this image on that exact folder??? what ever the solution may be.

I tried:

```
const imgPath = document.getElementById("imageFile").files[0];
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // Convert file to base64 string and save to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("image", reader.result);
}, false);

if (imgPath) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgPath);
}
```

but that is not what I want, I tried:

```
fs.writeFile();
```

couldn't figure it out, then I tried a NPM package - multer and this package is possible the answer I'm looking for but all the videos show the back-end code and not the front-end.

Comment: Is your second code block client-side or server-side code? Your text seems to imply server-side, but `document.querySelector` is a client-side command. I'm confused.

Comment: server-side, srry.

Comment: You may want to split this into two questions, one for the browser part and one for the server part. In both cases, you'll need to post the relevant code that you already have, e.g. the `signup` function or your http request handler.

Comment: #1 Do you mean to the multer  Disktorage http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html ? #2 Are you developing a monolith (back and front in the same workspace) or a spa+ microservice? #3 Could you share an example of your code?

Comment: @JRichardsz your answer help and I got it working thanks, it is a small project that I'm building, a small online shop, I'm doing it so I can learn and practice. Since your code worked I wonder 1 last thing... if it is possible to do the same thing with a <button onclick("function()")> instead of a <form>, if it is possible could you share the function??

Comment: Of course. Also to improve the question for future readers, if you can, change it to something like: "How upload data and files using ajax and express?"

Comment: Please, if this helped to solve your question, click the  arrow up  to mark as useful :D

Comment: I tried, it says "I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote"

Comment: Try to help someone with your knowledge to increase your reputation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload files using html or some client like postman you need to use this content-type: `multipart/form-data` with `<form>` or with `ajax`

### With <form>

```
<form id="registerForm" 
action="/upload" method="POST" 
autocomplete="off" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[image]

[image]

And then in the nodejs backend, you need to set the multer with the exact input name used in the html, **imageProfile** in this example

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('imageProfile'), function(req, res) {
```

**Complete code here**

app.js

```
const os = require('os');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path')
const xssEscape = require('xss-escape');

const multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "storage"))
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    var originalname = xssEscape(file.originalname);
    cb(null, originalname)
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('imageProfile'), function(req, res) {
  const imageProfile = req.file;
  console.log(imageProfile);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
  res.send("Ok");
});

app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at 5000`);
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
</head>
<body>
    <p>User registration</p>
    <form id="registerForm" action="/upload" method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label htmlFor="login">Username</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        <br><br>
        <label htmlFor="login">Image profile</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="imageProfile" name="imageProfile" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        <br><br>
        <div id="result" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "supervisor": "^0.12.0",
    "xss-escape": "0.0.6"
}
```

Due to default behavior of html form, a redirect is performed and the entire page is reloaded

[image]

### With Ajax

The previous approach is used since ancient days in which the page reloaded everything on each event. Today with modern javascript and frameworks like react, angular, vue, etc you could add cool effects to your web.

In this case,  is not required and you could use  and ajax to perform the post request

```
<p>User registration</p>

<label htmlFor="login">Username</label><br>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
<br><br>
<label htmlFor="login">Image profile</label><br>
<input type="file" id="imageProfile" name="imageProfile" />
<br><br>
<button id="registerButton" >Register</button> 
<br><br>
<div id="result" />

<script>

    var registerButton = document.getElementById("registerButton");
    registerButton.addEventListener("click", onRegisterEvent);

    function onRegisterEvent(e) {
        var data, xhr;

        data = new FormData();
        data.append('imageProfile', document.getElementById("imageProfile").files[0]);
        data.append('username', document.getElementById("username").value);

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', './upload', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function (response) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
        };
        xhr.send(data);
    }
</script>
```

### Advice

- Build a single nodejs in which the frontend (html) and the backend are in the same repository is just for small requirements. I advice you to develop a modern frontend with some spa(react/angular/vue) in one git repository and a microservice in another git repository
- Split the user registration in two steps:

  - simple key values
  - image update
- use docker, linux and a cloud for deployments
- https
- don't store the images directly on the disk. Use some service like aws s3 or similar